# How do I phrase this question naturally?

Tags: sentence-choice

A, "Is that not what happened?"

B, "No."

A, "What happened, then?" / "Then, what happened?" / "What did happen, then?" / "Then, what did happen?"

What can I use of these? Are they all natural here to native speakers?

Comment: All are equally natural to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

"What happened, then?" or "Then, what happened?"

For an English speaker, you can immediately throw away the last two options. Usually, I use the first one but the second one can also be used. It is completely on your preference because there is no exact rule on this.